# Run X programs in different color depths individually?

Tags: x11, xorg, colors, display

I am trying to run various programs on xorg in different color depth modes.

For example, I want to run my wm in 8 bit, but I want to run browsers in 16bit.

Is this possible? Many browsers do not work or load web pages in 8 bit color depth anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately X is not Amiga - where this was possible :)

What you can do, although it's not exactly what you want, is start two X instances on the same machine. One can be 8bit, the other 16bit.